# Remote Communication Service for WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, signalr

Im looking at creating a service on a remote server that a win forms app can communicate with. (Where the forms app is running locally on user machines).

The service can either run in IIS (7.5) or as a windows service, but essentially I need to be able to call the service from the forms app and then have a stream of progress sent back to the forms app from the service, much like you would output to a Console window.

I've looked into using WCF which seems ideal except I couldn't find out whether I can relay progress updates back to the forms app. Also SignalR running as a self hosted windows service seems to be an option but might be overkill?

We'll be running the forms app on win7 and the remote server will be running server 2008.

Are you able to advise best routes to go down for this and if possible some examples or tutorial links?

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the application to relay back to the server for progress, seems you are looking for something like this:
[WCF Duplex](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf/)

It basicly enable you to call bi-directional function using open socket.

Hope it helps.
Thanks,
Amir